# What is the nature of plasmids?

Tags: genetics, bacteriology, plasmids

What are the plasmids composed of? Are they composed of genomic or non-genomic DNA?

I guess the answer is "genomic DNA" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What definitions of "plasmid" and "genetic DNA" are you going by?

Comment: No...it's not a homework q...just one of my classmates was arguing about this....Actually I think you guys are just PARANOID about homework q....if it was a homework q. I think I have enough sense to put a 'homework' tag....

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean genomic and non-genomic DNA - [Plasmids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid) are small rings of non-genomic double-stranded DNA in Bacteria. They replicate mostly indepently of the genomic DNA can can occur from a few to several hundred copies per cell. See the illustration from the Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: Not only in bacteria.

Comment: @chris, yeah...